# is it possible to append google map to DOM after a specific event has fired?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

When I put google map script in **head** of my page, it makes my page to load slowly , and sometimes with some error(not important)

By google map script I mean this :

```
    <script type=text/javascript src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? key=&sensor='></script>
```

Now , is it possible that I do something like this:

```
      1- A modal shows
      2- $('script#befor_map').after("<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=false'></script>");
      3- google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize());
```

1. First a modal's fires
2. after that , I append google_map script after an existing script(called "befor_map)
3. after appending , I initialize the map

everything seems correct , but I get an error in my console as follows:

***Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined ***

and map doesn't execute

whats might be causing the problem ?

everything works fine , if I put map script in the header of the page without any method.

Comment: Try that instead: `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);`

Comment: have you ever read my question?:(

Comment: Ya, sorry but as i don't know what is `initialize` method, i was just speculating this method doesn't return another method. In this case, your code is wrong. Anyway, for sure this won't solve your issue regarding undefined variable google. To fix it, you need to call initialize function in onload handler of the google map script. Or maybe test: `$(window).on('load', initialize);`

Comment: See [Asynchronously Loading the API in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API)